# Changing values txt file with values from excel - matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, text-files

I'm a beginner in the world of MatLab, and hope you could get me in the right direction...

The situation is the following:

In excel for one variable I have 25 different values. Each single one of these values have to be written 24 times in a predefined textfile. 
At the end I should have 25 textfiles each with a different value of this variables (which occurs at 24 different places, but in the same column).

Is this clear? Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Kind regards,
Adrienne.

Comment: ok so what problem are you facing?

Comment: How can I find the specific strings in the textfile that have to be altered with matlab?

Comment: You want to write a variable in the text files. What does it have to do with finding specific strings in the text files? Also see [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you need a few functions for this. First you want the excel data in matlab. This is done with [xlsread](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html).

```
num = xlsread(filename);
```

Now you want to do the same thing 25 times. For this you use a [for-loop](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html).

```
for ct = 1:length(num)
    <code here>
end
```

To open a text file you use [fopen](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) to open, [fprintf](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write, and [fclose](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) to close.

```
fid=fopen(['textfile',num2str(ct),'.txt']);
fprintf(fid,num(ct));
fclose(fid)
```

and the total code should look like this:

```
num = xlsread(filename);
for ct = 1:length(num)
    fid=fopen(['textfile',num2str(ct),'.txt']);
    fprintf(fid,num(ct));
    fclose(fid)
end
```